# Rest Web Service with App Engine and Webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, web-applications

I want to build a REST web service on app engine. Currently i have this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

class UsersHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):  

def get(self, name):
    self.response.out.write('Hello '+ name+'!') 

def main():
util.run_wsgi_app(application)

#Map url like /rest/users/johnsmith
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/rest/users/(.*)',UsersHandler)]                                      
                                   debug=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And i would like to retreive for example all my users when the path /rest/users is accessed. I Imagine I can do this by building another handler, but I want to know if is possible to do it inside of this handler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to create a REST service with Google App Engine and Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788041/how-to-create-a-rest-service-with-google-app-engine-and-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, you can -- change your handler's `get` method to

```
def get(self, name=None):
    if name is None:
        """deal with the /rest/users case"""
    else:
        # deal with the /rest/users/(.*) case
        self.response.out.write('Hello '+ name+'!')
```

and your application to

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/rest/users/(.*)', UsersHandler),
                                      (r'/rest/users', UsersHandler)]                                      
                                     debug=True)
```

In other words, map your handler to all the URL patterns you want it to handle, and make sure the handler's `get` method can distinguish among them easily (typically via its arguments).

Comment: You could also use two handlers - one for "/rest/users/" and one for "/rest/users/(.+)".

Comment: @Nick, sure, but the OP knows that, as he says "I can do this by building another handler, but I want to know if is possible to do it inside of this handler" -- so I didn't repeat what he'd just said;-).