# WSGI - Set content type to JSON

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, wsgi

I'm crazy green to WSGI on Google App Engine (GAE).

How do I set the content type to JSON?  This is what I have so far:

```
class Instructions(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        response = {}
        response["message"] = "This is an instruction object"

        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))



application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/instructions', Instructions)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Additionally, I'm building a few RESTful services, nothing too complicated.  I was using restlets when I was developing in JAVA.  Is there a better framework to be using than WSGI?  The only reason I'm using WSGI is because that was what they used in the App Engine tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: You're "crazy green"? I hear that isn't easy.

Comment: Hey Nick, so I tried to write you a thank you not a while back for one of the questions that I had that you answered, but for the life of me I couldn't find your e-mail address

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the proper *Content-Type* with something like this:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

[WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wsgi) is not a framework but a specification; the framework you are currently using is the [webapp](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) framework.

There's nothing sophisticated and specific like Restlet on the Python side; however with webapp you can create [RESTful request handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788041/how-to-create-a-rest-service-with-google-app-engine-and-python/1789226#1789226) through regular expressions returning  JSON/XML data like your handler does.

Answer (score 2):

Like any HTTP response, you can add or edit headers:

```
def get(self):
    response = {}
    response["message"] = "This is an instruction object"

    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(response))
```

More here: [Redirects, Headers and Status Codes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better framework to be using than WSGI?

Look at Pyramid (previously named pylons, if you see that mentioned). It sounds like it'd be better in your case vs django.